# Why does my floating div overlap my footer on scroll instead of stopping at it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, footer

I'm trying to create a floating div, which I want to stop at the footer. I've added a `margin-top:50px` on my floating div, but it surpasses my footer. I need the margin-top to be 50px. How do I fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var length = $('#content').height() - $('#scroll-block').height() + $('#content').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        var height = $('#scroll-block').height() + 'px';

        if (scroll < $('#content').offset().top) {

            $('#scroll-block').css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'top': '0'
            });

        } else if (scroll > length) {

            $('#scroll-block').css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'bottom': '0',
                'top': 'auto'
            });

        } else {

            $('#scroll-block').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': '0',
                'height': height
            });

        }
    });

});
```

```css
#header {
    background: #c2c2c2;
    height: 150px;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 500px; /* Just as an example */
    width: 500px;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    background: #d7d7d7;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
}
#right {
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    float: right;
    height:200px;
}
#scroll-block {
    background: #0096d7;
    width: 150px;
    color: #fff;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:50px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
#footer {
    background: #c2c2c2;
    height: 500px; /* Just as an example */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="scroll-block">Sidebar Text here!</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">This is the text of the main part of the page.</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

Comment: Why do you "NEED" the `margin-top:50px`?

Comment: Why do you expect `margin-top` on your floating div to prevent it from overlapping your footer?

Comment: @WesFoster I need the margin-top 50px because i have a floating header which is 50px in height. And if I dont add the 50px on the margin-top, the floating div goes under my header.

Comment: @TylerH If you have a better solution, please tell me. Please read what I wrote to WesFoster

Comment: @WesFoster I dont want the div to touch the top also

Comment: @Bel I'm asking why you think that property will induce the layout behavior you seem to expect it to. `margin-top` on your floating div will have no effect on the bottom margin.

Comment: @Bel Also, you should look into `position: sticky` for your sidebar instead. In the next version of Chrome it will finally be supported again, and it's been supported for years in Firefox & Opera. It's also supported in Safari under a prefix. It is a native CSS property that does what your JavaScript is doing.